# Pagination in a vertically scrolling UICollectionview, how to manage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have called Web services and get no of data off from-data to two-data. I have scrolled the collection view to load more data of I have passed the from-data to two-data. I have been using scroll views, delegates method for using this pagination are managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set UIScrollView protocol - `UIScrollViewDelegate` and define the following Method.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
}
```

For [more details in this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:) : (base on www.developer.apple.com)

> Tells the delegate that the scroll view has ended decelerating the scrolling movement.
>
> Declaration (OBJECTIVE-C:)
>
> - (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
>
> Parameters
>
> scrollView : The scroll-view object that is decelerating the scrolling of the content view.
>
> Discussion
>
> The scroll view calls this method when the scrolling movement comes to a halt. The decelerating property of UIScrollView controls deceleration.
>
> Availability:
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

For use this code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float endScrolling = (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height);
    if (endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
    {
        //Manage Pagination
        from_Post = from_Data + Page_Number; //Like 10, 20 as you define
        to_Post = to_Data + Page_Number; //Like 10, 20 as you define

        //Called Function for You Performing action
        [self GetDataFrom:from_Post To:to_Post];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Swift

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let endScrolling = (scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height)
    
    if endScrolling >= scrollView.contentSize.height {
        
        //Manage Pagination
        //from_Post = from_Data + Page_Number; //Like 10, 20 as you define
        //to_Post = to_Data + Page_Number; //Like 10, 20 as you define

        //Called Function for You Performing action
        //[self GetDataFrom:from_Post To:to_Post];            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the collection view's delegate to self, and implement the methods of UIScrollDelegate like below:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{  
    //Get the page
    NSInteger page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width;   
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (!decelerate) {
        //Get the page
        NSInteger page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.bounds.size.width;
    }
}
```